# Some direction on testing with have_selector?

Tags: ruby, rspec2

Following is my show.html.haml file:

```
%h3
  = gravatar_for @employee
  %p
  #details
  = @employee.emp_full_name
  #spacing
  = @employee.email
```

Next, here is my application_helper file that defines title:

```
module ApplicationHelper

def logo
 logo = image_tag("rails.png", :alt => "Time and it's Cost", class:  "round")
end

# Return title on a per-page basis.
def title
  base_title = "Time and it's Cost"
  if @title.nil?
    base_title
  else
    "#{base_title} | #{@title}"
  end
 end
end
```

And, here is my spec/requests/employee_pages_spec file:

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe "Employee pages" do
  subject { page }
    describe "employee show page" do
    let(:employee) { FactoryGirl.create(:employee) }
    before { visit employee_path(employee) }

    it { should have_selector('h3',  employee.emp_full_name) }
    it { should have_selector('title',  text: employee.emp_full_name) }
    end
end
```

As can be seen from my 'show page', I have a 'h3' selector but I also have '#details' tag that I think is the cause of my 'h3' test failing. I am not sure how to get to the #details in order to test it? Also since my title is in application_helper I am at a loss as to how to test for it?

Anyone have some ideas they can share with me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea: did you mean to use :content => employee.emp_full_name (webrat) or :text => (capbybara) in the calls to have_selector ?

Here's another idea: h3 can contain mixtures of elements, but it isn't quite normal and p elements aren't normally empty.

Just for illustration, we can go to http://haml-lang.com/try.html and enter this:
(not using = since it doesn't do the inline ruby evaluation on that site)

```
%h3
  "gravatar_for employee"
  %p
  #details
  "employee.emp_full_name"
  #spacing
  "employee.email"
```

We get this:

```
<h3>
  "gravatar_for employee"
  <p></p>
  <div id='details'></div>
  "employee.emp_full_name"
  <div id='spacing'></div>
  "employee.email"
</h3>
```

You could make the selectors more specific by wrapping the names in span elements, and/or fixing your markup. I'm assuming you didn't mean the div or p to be empty. Adjusting the indentation and you could make the matching more specific (faster) too.